# How to display key values in HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

Can someone show me how can I display Monday, Tuesday... in a column of HTML table. I want to display the whole object in the tabular format and show it in an HTML page. What can be done?

```
this.dietplan={
                        "week1": {
                          "Monday": [
                            {
                              "time": "10:00 AM",
                              "diet": "3 eggs",
                              "calories": "150"
                            },
                            {
                              "time": "12:00 PM",
                              "diet": "2 eggs",
                              "calories": "100"
                            }
                          ],
                          "Tuesday": [
                            {
                              "time": "10:00 AM",
                              "diet": "3 eggs",
                              "calories": "150"
                            },
                            {
                              "time": "12:00 PM",
                              "diet": "2 eggs",
                              "calories": "100"
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
```

Comment: what do you already tried? please share your tries.

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh I tried this
 <tr *ngFor="let diet of dietplan | keyvalue">
        <td >{{diet.key}}</td>
      </tr>
but this is giving me output as week1.

Comment: It will give you "week1" because your strcuture´s first layer are weeks. So do you also want to show your weeks within your table? how do you want to show your table? But the pipe is a good way so far, but you have to get clear what you want to display. then you have to transform your datastructure to handle in your html.

Comment: the answer is no.

Comment: @J.Knabenschuh I want to show like

Monday    "time": "10:00 AM",
                 "diet": "3 eggs",
                 "calories": "150"

                 "time": "12:00 PM",
                 "diet": "2 eggs",
                 "calories": "100"

Tuesday     same as above

Comment: @NegiRox what can be done then?

Comment: will you have multiple week plans like week1 and week2 and so on and do you want to display them in the same table if you want what it should look like

Comment: @Anusha_Mamidala yes i will have multiple weeks as you said, and each will week have days monday to sunday.

Comment: we can show your diet plan of any day in tabular format

Comment: @NegiRox how ? can you please tell

Comment: Can you please share any pictorial representation of how it should look like.. so that i can help you out creating table

Comment: @Anusha_Mamidala https://ibb.co/KDqfZc4

Comment: I updated my version corresponding to your snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like the following - see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-week-table

html

```
<table class="table table-hover" [id]="mytable"> 
  <tbody> 
    <ng-container *ngFor="let diet of dietplan | keyvalue"> 
      <tr *ngFor="let day of diet.value | keyvalue | sortWeekday">
        <td>{{day.key}}</td> 
        <ng-container *ngFor="let row of day.value"> 
          <td>{{row.time || string}}<br> {{row.diet || string}}<br> {{row.calories || string}}<br></td>
        </ng-container> 
      </ng-container>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

ts

```
  dietplan={"week1": {
              "Monday": [
                {
                  "time": "10:00 AM",
                  "diet": "3 eggs",
                  "calories": "150"
                },
                {
                  "time": "12:00 PM",
                  "diet": "2 eggs",
                  "calories": "100"
                }
              ],
              "Tuesday": [
                {
                  "time": "10:00 AM",
                  "diet": "3 eggs",
                  "calories": "150"
                },
                {
                  "time": "12:00 PM",
                  "diet": "2 eggs",
                  "calories": "100"
                }
              ]
            }
          };
```

pipe ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'sortWeekday'})
export class SortWeekdayPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(weekdays: any[]): any[] {
    weekdays.sort((a, b) => {
      let sortedWeekdays = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Staurday', 'Sunday'];

      return sortedWeekdays.indexOf(a.key) - sortedWeekdays.indexOf(b.key);
    });
    return weekdays;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked, but for me the output of days is not coming in serial order.
output:
https://ibb.co/s3TJ0MF

Comment: I tweaked your code little bit:
I tweaked your angular code to this:
<table class="table table-hover" [id]="mytable">
        <tbody>
          <ng-container *ngFor="let diet of dietplan | keyvalue">
            <tr *ngFor="let day of diet.value | keyvalue"><td>{{day.key}}</td>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let row of day.value">
              <td>{{row.time || string}}<br>
              {{row.diet || string}}<br>
              {{row.calories || string}}<br></td>
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </tbody>
      </table>

Comment: I updated my post with your tweak. To get right order you have to sort the values. Because of your datastructure you have to sort by the weekday name. Easiest way to achieve that, is to right your own sort pipe sorting statically by weekday-name.

Comment: Now I also added the pipe see the fiddle in my post, I also updated the sourecode. Hope it helped, if so please mark the post

Comment: Thank you, you are a life savior :)

Answer (score -2):

you can see a below code  to generate table from json

```
var _table_ = document.createElement('table'),
    _tr_ = document.createElement('tr'),
    _th_ = document.createElement('th'),
    _td_ = document.createElement('td');

// Builds the HTML Table out of myList json data from Ivy restful service.
 function buildHtmlTable(arr) {
     var table = _table_.cloneNode(false),
         columns = addAllColumnHeaders(arr, table);
     for (var i=0, maxi=arr.length; i < maxi; ++i) {
         var tr = _tr_.cloneNode(false);
         for (var j=0, maxj=columns.length; j < maxj ; ++j) {
             var td = _td_.cloneNode(false);
                 cellValue = arr[i][columns[j]];
             td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][columns[j]] || ''));
             tr.appendChild(td);
         }
         table.appendChild(tr);
     }
     return table;
 }

 // Adds a header row to the table and returns the set of columns.
 // Need to do union of keys from all records as some records may not contain
 // all records
 function addAllColumnHeaders(arr, table)
 {
     var columnSet = [],
         tr = _tr_.cloneNode(false);
     for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i < l; i++) {
         for (var key in arr[i]) {
             if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key) && columnSet.indexOf(key)===-1) {
                 columnSet.push(key);
                 var th = _th_.cloneNode(false);
                 th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
                 tr.appendChild(th);
             }
         }
     }
     table.appendChild(tr);
     return columnSet;
 }
var source={
                          "Monday": [
                            {
                              "time": "10:00 AM",
                              "diet": "3 eggs",
                              "calories": "150"
                            },
                            {
                              "time": "12:00 PM",
                              "diet": "2 eggs",
                              "calories": "100"
                            }
                          ],
                          "Tuesday": [
                            {
                              "time": "10:00 AM",
                              "diet": "3 eggs",
                              "calories": "150"
                            },
                            {
                              "time": "12:00 PM",
                              "diet": "2 eggs",
                              "calories": "100"
                            }
                          ]
                        }

document.body.appendChild(buildHtmlTable(source["Monday"]));
```

see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/qp0wdu16/)